# Check failed: CheckException(env) with music_player plugin

Tags: exception, flutter, audio-player

```
Resolving dependencies...
Running 'gradlew assembleDebug'...
Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk...
I/FlutterActivityDelegate( 4488): onResume setting current activity to this
F/flutter ( 4488): [FATAL:flutter/shell/platform/android/platform_view_android_jni.cc(60)] Check failed: CheckException(env). 
Error connecting to the service protocol: TimeoutException: Request to Dart VM Service timed out: _flutter.listViews({})
```

How can I solve it? Any help, please.

Comment: I get this error on hot-reload. This is a known issue. Where do you get this error?

Comment: When i try to run the example from flute_music_player.dart (https://github.com/iampawan/Flute-Music-Player/tree/master/example)

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to replicate the same behavior as observed.

I've checked the plugin and it seems that it's not being maintained for years and it's not compatible with the current version of Dart (Dart 3). I suggest use a similar plugin like:

- [assets_audio_player](https://pub.dev/packages/assets_audio_player)
- [just_audio](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio)